# Explicit operator cast on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, kentico, ascx

I'm working on a asp.net project in Kentico.

Currently I created a Model, let's call it PartnerModel. It contains a private variable of the type TreeNode, which basically holds the same informations in a different form.

I want to be able to cast an instance of a PartnerModel explicit to a TreeNode.
This should happen at runtime (in a WebForms User Control).

**Edit:** I'm not searching for "better" ways to achieve something like I'm asking for. This is more a general purpose with no explicit use case. The code below is just what I tried to do. I just want to know, if it is possible to cast my model explicit during runtime and if so, how I can do it.

Is this possible? I just get an InvalidCast Exception.

*PartnerModel.cs*

```
public class PartnerModel
{
        #region Public Properties

        public TreeNode Node { get { return node; } }
        ...
        public static explicit operator TreeNode(PartnerModel model)
        {
            return model.node;
        }
}
```

*PartnerOverview.ascx*

```
...
<cms:BasicRepeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterPartner">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="<%# ((CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode)Container.DataItem).RelativeURL %>">
...
```

Comment: Instead of "casting it" you could parse it.

Comment: Indeed I could, but thats not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Are you sure `Container.DataItem` is really a `PartnerModel`? Have you tried casting it to `PartnerModel` first?

Comment: The exception states: "Message: Unable to cast object of type 'CMSApp.Models.PartnerModel' to type 'CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode'.". So yeah - I'm kind of sure it is :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very good way of approaching this scenario. Especially in MVC (but also in other types of projects) you should use **projections** in your presentation layer instead of using the underlying database models directly. That is why projects such as [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) exist

In your case the best practise would be to create a Model which contains all properties from TreeNode class you want to use in your transformation + custom ones and then use this model in the presentation.

Example of model:

```
public class PartnerViewModel
{
    // partner specific properties
    public string PartnerName { get; set; }
    public int PartnerID { get; set; }

    // node properties
    public int NodeID { get; set; }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
}
```

In your presentation layer you should work only with this `PartnerViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are binding a collection of `PartnerModel` objects, you can cast `Container.DataItem` to your type, and then access the `Node` property.

```csharp
...
<cms:BasicRepeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterPartner">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<%# ((PartnerModel)Container.DataItem).Node.RelativeURL %>">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The cast operators in C#, whether implicit or explicit are handled at the compile time (used the type information available at compile time), it is just syntax sugar.

What you really do here is casting Object (type of DataItem property) to TreeNode. The compiler does not really have any way to recognize it should use your operator.

You would have to tell it what is the source type by writing it like this which really doesn't bring the value you expect I guess:

```
<%# ((CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode)(PartnerModel)Container.DataItem).RelativeURL %>
```

What you see in the exception is a message from the default cast operator, which doesn't know about your operator and probably doesn't have any code to attach some customization at run-time, and therefore isn't able to perform the conversion.